# Mongo read large amount of data

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, database-performance

I have a mongo collection with 115M documents and size is around 200 GB .

The _id is like **"bbsr/13/pressure/1573689600000"**. The last element is unix timestamp.
Now i need to get all documents where  **_id :/bbsr/13/pressure/** .  or **_id startsWith bbsr/13/pressure**. Here, **"bbsr/13/pressure" is the identifier**.

I tried pagination(skip and limit) with _id regex, it takes around 1 hour to give all documents(330000 in number).

I tried range based query **{_id={$gte=bbsr/13/pressure/1573689600000, $lt=bbsr/13/pressure/1574121600000}}** . Even this takes more than one hour.

For one single identifier to give all documents in both the approaches, it takes more than one hour.

I would like to get all documents for a given identifier by at most 10 minutes.

How do deal with efficiently ?

I am using java to fetch the values.

Comment: Please format your JSON, so that it is more readable.

Comment: Are you able to run an update on the collection to modify the data to make this work going forward?

Answer (score 1):

I think your biggest issue is the fact that you are trying to search by content inside your custom `_id`. What you should be doing is storing the timestamp on a separate property and have that indexed, then just filter by that timestamp property alone. Searching will be much faster with this.

Also, is there a specific reason you need the custom `_id` instead of just letting it auto-generate? I would make each segment in your `_id` field separate properties instead. The regex parsing of that segmented `_id` is definitely your culprit. It's way faster to search on individual properties.